Typeorm find - select fields of nested relations
I have an entity with nested relations, and I want to select a certain field from the nested relation. This is my query:
const data = await this.entityRepository.find({
  select: {
    id: true,
    code: true,
    description: true,
    groupDetails: {
      primaryGroup: {
        id: true,
      },
    },
  },
  relations: {
    groupDetails: {
      primaryGroup: true,
      secondaryGroup: true,
    },
  }
});

I've expected to get groupDetails.primaryGroup.id in the res objects, but the field groupDetails doesn't appear in any of them.
If I remove it from the select like this:
const data = await this.entityRepository.find({
  select: {
    id: true,
    code: true,
    description: true,
  },
  relations: {
    groupDetails: {
      primaryGroup: true,
      secondaryGroup: true,
    },
  }
});

I do get groupDetails in the res objects.
How can I achieve the functionality i'm looking for?

Try to add select of groupDetails "id" (I presume "id" is a referenceColumnName). So your query looks like:
const data = await this.entityRepository.find({
  select: {
    id: true,
    code: true,
    description: true,
    groupDetails: {
      id: true,
      primaryGroup: {
        id: true,
      },
    },
  },
  relations: {
    groupDetails: {
      primaryGroup: true,
      secondaryGroup: true,
    },
  }
});

